# IOS app How to get data from server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to create my first iPhone application and was hoping someone could direct me in the correct path.

I am trying to build an iPhone app that can communicate back and forth from a server?
(example. I want to create a login/registration page that will authenticate through the mysql database I have)

That's my one main question because I am not sure how to do that, My website I have written in PHP so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be so helpful!

Comment: If you're familiar with web technologies and not with iOS programming, something like [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) may be something for you. If not, a complete tutorial is almost impossible to fit into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many Open Source library to do it easly.

I really recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), but another alternative are:

1. LRResty
2. RestKit
3. AWS SDK for iOS
4. ShareKit
5. NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection (suggested by #ceyquem).

With these library you save a lot of time. Then you only need to create a WS (maybe in php) that receive the login parameters and send a response in XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP/HTTPS Requests, see the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html

Comment: So making HTTP/HTTPS Requests can communicate to the MYSQL database for user authentication login/Register? My website that I have is written in PHP - will this be ok or is there a way to use PHP request (if that's a thing with in xcode)

Comment: You should have specific php pages for you app, that you will query from your app using HTTP/HTTPS requests. Their answer can be in XML format if you have lists for instance, or simple text as a return code if you want to execute a query (INSERT, UPDATE...).

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly - Write the php login/ registration authentication code for the website to use but within the app I write HTTP/HTTPS requests to talk to the server retrieve that information on whether or not a user can login or create an account? Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Yes, for a login you capture the login/pw variables in the app native code then you call to a php page passing the login/pw variables using GET or POST. You should use HTTPS for that also to protect the data transmitted.

Comment: Awesome - is there any example code I could look at? I'm going to attempt writing this code. I'll post my results then when write it.